# Compiling NVIDIA's Quadro FX SDK (NVGVOSDK) on Windows XP

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp, nvidia

I've got an NVIDIA Quadro FX 4800 card hooked up in a Windows XP box and I am trying to compile and run some code using the [NVGVOSDK](https://partners.nvidia.com/index.asp?sessargs=4C0143E9E03C470293A4072D096DC5A3). This SDK is not very well documented and is rather old. I downloaded version 1.2 from the NVIDIA Partners site which is from 2007 but appears to be the latest version.

I am trying to compile and run some of the examples that come with the download. I tried specifically running the "textcrawl" example using the provided "NVGVOExamples2003.sln" Solution file in Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I had to remove references to GLaux to get the example to compile and link successfully. When I try to run it, I get the following error in a pop-up window: "This application has failed to start because NvCpl.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

The NvCpl.dll is located at "C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcpl.dll" and I am pretty sure it is properly registered as I have no problems using the NVIDIA Control Panel.

I am fairly new to development on Windows, so I am not sure if this is an NVGVOSDK specific issue, or if it's just the way I am linking things in Visual C++. Any insight or suggestions welcome.